# Why wp_enqueue_script() not work in my plugin?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

```
function user_enqueue_script() {
    global $pluginsURI;
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'modernizr-script', $pluginsURI.'js/modernizr.custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'user_enqueue_script' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
plugins_url() . '/' . 'your_pluhin_folder'
```

Instead of your global $pluginsURI;

Thats the only thing I see that could go wrong there.